# C# Server to Android Client Behind the NAT

Tags: c#, android, tcp, nat, sdp

I need to establish a connection from a public ip server implemented in c  sharp to an android device behind the NAT and I was able to got SPD message from the android device using ICE4j library using this code

```
String toSend = SdpUtils.createSDPDescription(agent); //Each computer sends this information
```

and I got the following message

v=0 
o=ice4j.org 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.1.14
s=-
t=0 0
a=ice-options:trickle
a=ice-ufrag:dikj41a5eequb2
a=ice-pwd:3t07qqjndu5pkneh53c6kqti3l
m=audio 5000 RTP/AVP 0
c=IN 192.168.1.14 IP4
a=mid:audio
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2130706431 fe80::1afe:34ff:fe29:c233 5000 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.14 5000 typ host
a=candidate:3 1 udp 1677724415 91.93.202.127 5000 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.14 rport 5000

and the server stores this message so my question is what I have to do to establish a connection from the server to the android device using these information

Comment: Your server should generate SDP as well and send it to the android phone. After they both have each others SDP, ICE check starts.

Comment: ok, so my question is there is any library that could do this for me or any point to start with, any help will be appreciated. @Tahlil